# control+c is not working

Tags: linux, mips, sigint

I am using linux 2.6.32.13-Cavium-Octeon with MIPS architecture. On terminal when i press ctrl+c to terminate process; nothing happen. How can I trace this in my kernel to handle with it issue?
`stty -a` output is:

```
`speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke`
```

Is there any issue with tty? Because when i `make menuconfig` there is no option for "enable tty"
and command `bind -v` is also not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.) You can press Ctrl+z to put the process to sleep
2.) Then do "kill -9 process-pid", where you find the process's pid with 'ps' and other tools. On Bash (and possibly other shells) you can do "kill -9 %1" (or '%N' in general) which is easier.
3.) If Ctrl+z doesn't work, you'll have to open another terminal and kill from there.

Comment: `SIGKILL` (kill -9) is meant as a last resort. If you want to interrupt your process, send SIGINT.

Comment: Michael: I think you have given the same thing, can you please explain in more detail about SIGINT ?